# validate() function redirect in chrome browser not showing any validation errors (more than 3 errors)

Tags: php, google-chrome, laravel-5.4, laravel-validation, laravel-session

Laravel 5.4 version

The validate() function works until I test more than 3 errors in the form. Upon automatic redirect after buildfailedvalidationresponse function, the 4 $error messages aren't present on and neither is the old form data. This only doesn't work in chrome. Firefox/internet explorer is fine. I have data dumped throughout the process of validatesrequest file and it shows the $error variables being passed correctly to the buildfailedvalidationresponse function but no errors/old form data are presented after redirect. I was just wondering if anybody has had an issue like this with different browsers.

validation method

```
     protected function validateRegistration(Request $request) {

     $rules = array(

     'name' => 'required|string',
     'email' => array('required','string','email','unique:users,email'),
     'phone' => 'required|digits:10',
     'userid' => array('required','string','min:6','max:10','unique:users,userid','regex:/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/'),
     'password' => array('required','string','min:8','max:12','regex:/^(?
      =.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*(_|[^\w])).+$/'),
    'repeatedpassword' => 'required|string|same:password',

    'code' => 'required|digits:4|exists:codes,code'
);

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    if ($this) {
        $store = new User();
        return $store->insertuser();
    }
```

}

blade validation display errors statement

```
<div class="container">
    @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li> {{ $error }} </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show some code to reproduce this error? For such a complicated task, a public git repository would be helpful.

Comment: just posted what i have in my controller and what method displays the errors on my view